# Textfield add a character in the end after I add attributedText for the textfield in swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I want to add `attributedText` to a `textfield`.

My code:

```
let emailArray = ["Abraham", "John Doe", "John Smith", "Awesome"]

func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool
{
    for value in self.emailArray {

        print(value)
        print(textField.text!)

        if(value.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(textField.text! + string))
        {
            print(range.location)
            print(value)
            var attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: value)

            //attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)], range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 6))
            attributedText.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()], range: NSRange(location: (range.location + 1), length: (value.characters.count - range.location - 1)))

            textField.attributedText = attributedText

            print(textField.text)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

When I taped `'a'` in the `textfield`, I can check out `Abraham` in the `emailArray`, after I set `attributedText` of `Abraham` to the `textfield`.
But There is a problem, the result of `textfield` show `Abrahama`, the `textfield` add a `'a'` in the end automatic...how can I delete the `'a'`?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line `textField.attributedText = attributedText` add

```
return false
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well ! I have another quesiton, I am doing autocomplete, I don't want to use tableview now. so I set other characters gray, only 'a' is black. I think I will set cursor position. Do you some suggestion for textfield autocomplete without tableview? Thank you very much.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758093/ios-autocomplete-feature . If that does not help then you should post it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have posted it, it is different with the post you had given me. Could you see my question ? Thank you.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986529/textfield-add-a-character-in-the-end-after-i-add-attributedtext-for-the-textfiel)